# Is there a limitation on who can build/create an ad-hoc distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm absolutely sure a few months ago I read somewhere that only one team member could build/create a package for ad-hoc distribution.

But now I can't find any reference to that anywhere, was I mistaken?

At the moment I am creating and distributing the builds within our company but am about to go on holiday and thus trying to find if there will be any problems with somebody else doing this while I am away.

Comment: I've never heard that, perhaps you're thinking uploading the binary to itunes connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a provisioning profile any developer on the team can sign and release ad-hoc builds. However...

> Only team agents and admins can create a distribution provisioning
>   profile

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html